# Countdown timer for time-based game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have a game in which the objective is to shoot as many (randomly generated) enemy ships as possible but I want to add a 30 second timer counting down to zero to add a time limit in, but I am not sure how I would do it? I have several AS files with all of my code in to generate different sized ships at different speeds and whatnot, so if snippets of code are needed, I will add them.

I tried doing it this way and it didn't work:

```
var gameTime:Number = 30;
var gameTimer:Timer;
static var timeText:TextField = new TextField();

timeText = new TextField();
timeText.x = 560;
timeText.y = 0;
timeText.text = gameTime.toString();
addChild(timeText);

gameTimer = new Timer(30000, gameTime);
gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, gameTimeCount);
gameTimer.start();

function gameTimeCount(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    gameTime--;
    timeText.text = gameTime.toString();
}
```

But the count stays at 30 and doesn't go down.

What I have now:

Comment: You have your Timer set for 30000 milliseconds per tick. That's 30 seconds. you want that to be 1000, which is 1 second. That's how often you should update.

Comment: you aren't updating your timeHeader.  I commented in the `updateTime` handler `//update your user interface as needed`. Try adding this line to that handler -- `timeHeader.text = "Time : " + String(gameTime);` - It works perfectly for me.

Comment: I just cut/pasted the code you have above, and it works flawlessly. How wide is your page ? is it possible that you have that textfield  timeText positioned off the stage ? What is the width of your stage ?

Comment: I looked at your file, and it was a issue with how you were setting your font formats for that text field that was making the text disappear. The counter works just fine. Use `timeText.defaultFormat = scoreFormat;` BEFORE you set the text initially. Please accept my answer as it works just fine. If you have further formatting issues, just open a new question on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this :

```
// in class variable declarations
public var gameTime:int;
public var levelDuration:int;

// where you want to start it 
levelDuration = 30;
gameTime = levelDuration;
var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,levelDuration);
gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);
gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timeExpired)
gameTimer.start();


function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    // your class variable tracking each second, 
    gameTime--;
    //update your user interface as needed

}

function timeExpired(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var gameTimer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime)
    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeExpired)

    // do whatever you need to do for game over
}
```

This code works just fine, you need to do as the updateTime function comment suggests :

`//update your user interface as needed`

Based on your code in your post, you need to adjust that function to look like this :

```
function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace(gameTime);
    // your class variable tracking each second, 
    gameTime--;
    //update your user interface as needed
    timeHeader.text = "Time : " + String(gameTime);

}
```

I added a trace too, so you can see that it is indeed updating each second.

Comment: I edited this to countdown. Not sure how else I can help you, this will work.

Comment: Updated answer to use gameTime like in yours. I misunderstood and thought you wanted to track how many seconds have expired.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but it was just starting the timer at 0 and not from 30?

Comment: I modified it, did you get the latest version ? are you setting gameTime to the value of level duration at the beginning ?

Comment: Look at the code in my answer -- `gameTime = levelDuration;` and the line before that, `levelDuration = 30;`  If you have both of those lines, how could gameTime be set to 0 ?

Comment: You'll need to post your current code or something, you are missing something from my answer.

Comment: I used your updated code and it works fine, but you aren't updating your user interface. I updated my answer to isolate what you are not taking note of.

Comment: I've pasted this in and what now happens is it shows `Time: 30` in the top corner but then after a second or two, the `30` disappears but in the Output window in Flash it displays the time counting down (Shows as 30, 29, 28 etc. on separate lines)

Comment: can you post exactly what you have now. I used what you had posted but since removed, and added one line and it worked perfectly. The trace is just showing you what the variable holds. You must have copied something incorreclty

Comment: if you want to email me at prototype.in.training@gmail.com we can just get this done quickly. I think you are either miscopying or misunderstanding some aspect. The code posted in this answer works flawlessly so long as you have a timeHeader text field. Whatever problems you are having with this code have to do with you actually updating the text in your textfield.

Comment: Emailed you (kmjoinery@gmail.com)

Comment: the code works great for me, what is your stage width ? only thing I can think of is that you have that textfield positioned off the stage.